# C/C++: Variable Reset to 0 after scanf() Input for Next Variable

Tags: c, printf, scanf, signed

I've written a program that will take in various inputs to generate a list of ADC counts for an NTC thermistor across a temperature range. I've ran this in both Pelles C and GCC (vs code + MINgw). I'm seeing minTemp getting reset to 0 after maxTemp input is provided by the user. Prior to that it holds its value. I'm using -40 as the input to minTemp.

Why is minTemp being set to 0 when maxTemp gets its value from the user?

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/******************************************************************************
* Defines
******************************************************************************/
/*! @brief 0 degree Celsius converted to Kelvin. */
#define NTC_DEGC_0                                  (273.15)
/*! @brief Maximal voltage (5V). */
#define NTC_VCOM                                    (5.0)
/*! @brief Resolution of measured voltage in Volts (U = 152.58789 uV *
 *  register_value), with 5V maximal voltage. */
#define NTC_REGISTER_RES                            (0.00015258789) // Can be calculated from ADC resolution and ADC reference voltage

/******************************************************************************
* Types
***************************************************************************** */
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t beta;         /*!< Beta parameter of NTC thermistor in [K].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint32_t rntc;         /*!< R_NTC - NTC fixed resistance in [Ohm].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint32_t refRes;       /*!< NTC Reference Resistance in [Ohm].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint8_t refTemp;       /*!< NTC Reference Temperature in degrees [Celsius].
                                Admissible range is from 0 to 200. */
} ntc_config_t;

/******************************************************************************
* Local Variables
******************************************************************************/
long double NtcRegisterRes;

/******************************************************************************
* Function Prototypes
******************************************************************************/
static void FillNtcTable(const ntc_config_t* const ntcConfig, int16_t minTemp,
                         int16_t maxTemp, uint16_t table[]);

/******************************************************************************
* Global Functions
******************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
    ntc_config_t ntcConfig;
    long double voltRef = 5.0;
    long double res;
    int16_t minTemp = -40;
    int16_t maxTemp;
    uint16_t *table;
    int tableSize = 0;

    printf("This program will generate the NTC table based on various inputs.\n\n");
    // Beta
    printf("Beta: ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.beta);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.beta);

    // Pull up resistance
    printf("Pull-up Resistance: ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.rntc);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.rntc);

    // Reference temp
    printf("Reference Temperature (Degrees C): ");
    scanf("%hhu", &ntcConfig.refTemp);
    printf("%hhu\n", ntcConfig.refTemp);

    // Reference resistance
    printf("Reference Resistance (Ohms): ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.refRes);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.refRes);

    // ADC voltage reference
    printf("ADC Reference Voltage: ");
    scanf("%Lf", &voltRef);
    printf("%Lf\n", voltRef);

    // ADC resolutions (in bits)
    printf("ADC Resolution (in bits): ");
    scanf("%Lf", &res);
    printf("%Lf\n", res);

    // NTC Register Resolution
    NtcRegisterRes = (long double)voltRef / pow(2, res);
    printf("%Le\n", NtcRegisterRes);

    // Min Temp for Table
    printf("Min Temp: ");
    scanf("%d", &minTemp);

    // Max Temp for Table
    printf("Max Temp: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxTemp);
    printf("max temp: %d\n", maxTemp);
    
    printf("min temp: %d\n", minTemp);
    tableSize = (maxTemp + abs(minTemp)) + 1;
    printf("table size: %d\n", tableSize);
    table = (uint16_t *)malloc(tableSize * sizeof(uint16_t));
    FillNtcTable(&ntcConfig, minTemp, maxTemp, table);
    
    // Print table
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        printf("Temp:\t%d\tADC:\t%d\n", (minTemp+i), table[i]);
    }

    // Free the memory
    free(table);

    return(0);
}

/******************************************************************************
* Local Functions
******************************************************************************/
/*!
 * @brief This function fills the NTC look up table.
 *
 * NTC look up table is intended for resistance to temperature conversion.
 * An array item contains raw value from a register. Index of the item is
 * temperature value.
 *
 * ArrayItem = (Vcom * Rntc) / (0.00015258789 * (NTC + Rntc))
 * Where:
 *  - ArrayItem is an item value of the table,
 *  - Vcom is maximal voltage (5V),
 *  - NTC is the resistance of NTC thermistor (Ohm),
 *  - 0.00015258789 is resolution of measured voltage in Volts
 *    (V = 152.58789 uV * Register_value),
 *  - Rntc is value of a resistor connected to Vcom (see MC3377x datasheet,
 *    section MC3377x PCB components).
 *
 * Beta formula used to calculate temperature based on NTC resistance:
 *   1 / T = 1 / T0 + (1 / Beta) * ln(Rt / R0)
 * Where:
 *  - R0 is the resistance (Ohm) at temperature T0 (Kelvin),
 *  - Beta is material constant (Kelvin),
 *  - T is temperature corresponding to resistance of the NTC thermistor.
 *
 * Equation for NTC value is given from the Beta formula:
 *   NTC = R0 * exp(Beta * (1/T - 1/T0))
 *
 * @param ntcConfig Pointer to NTC components configuration.
 */
static void FillNtcTable(const ntc_config_t* const ntcConfig, int16_t minTemp,
                         int16_t maxTemp, uint16_t table[])
{
    double ntcVal;
    double expArg;
    uint16_t i = 0;
    int32_t temp;

    for (temp = minTemp; temp <= maxTemp; temp++)
    {
        expArg = ntcConfig->beta * ((1.0 / (NTC_DEGC_0 + temp)) - (1.0 / (NTC_DEGC_0 + ntcConfig->refTemp)));
        ntcVal = exp(expArg) * ntcConfig->refRes;
        table[i] = (uint16_t)round(((NTC_VCOM * ntcVal) / (ntcVal + (double)ntcConfig->rntc)) / NtcRegisterRes);
        i++;
    }
}
```

minTemp Input: -40
maxtemp Input: 125
List generates for only 0 - 126. After stepping through in vs code, mintemp gets reset when maxTemp gets its value after scanf(). Not sure why.

Comment: always check the scanf return value

Comment: You're using ```scanf``` and ```malloc``` without checking their return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue so you can use scanf with `int16_t` without having to create extra variables and such.

Here is a glimpse of the output:

```bash
Min Temp: 7
Max Temp: 8
max temp: 8
min temp: 7
table size: 16
Temp:   7       ADC:    43
Temp:   8       ADC:    43
```

The solution I found was to use the library `inttypes.h`, then change the `scanf` from `scanf("%d", &minTemp);` to `scanf("%" SCNd16, &minTemp);`:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
// More code here
scanf("%" SCNd16, &minTemp);
```

This is supposed to be part of the [C99 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.26.4)

Here is the whole code so you can copy and paste:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS

/******************************************************************************
* Defines
******************************************************************************/
/*! @brief 0 degree Celsius converted to Kelvin. */
#define NTC_DEGC_0                                  (273.15)
/*! @brief Maximal voltage (5V). */
#define NTC_VCOM                                    (5.0)
/*! @brief Resolution of measured voltage in Volts (U = 152.58789 uV *
 *  register_value), with 5V maximal voltage. */
#define NTC_REGISTER_RES                            (0.00015258789) // Can be calculated from ADC resolution and ADC reference voltage

/******************************************************************************
* Types
******************************************************************************/
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t beta;         /*!< Beta parameter of NTC thermistor in [K].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint32_t rntc;         /*!< R_NTC - NTC fixed resistance in [Ohm].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint32_t refRes;       /*!< NTC Reference Resistance in [Ohm].
                                Admissible range is from 1 to 1000000. */
    uint8_t refTemp;       /*!< NTC Reference Temperature in degrees [Celsius].
                                Admissible range is from 0 to 200. */
} ntc_config_t;

/******************************************************************************
* Local Variables
******************************************************************************/
long double NtcRegisterRes;

/******************************************************************************
* Function Prototypes
******************************************************************************/
static void FillNtcTable(const ntc_config_t* const ntcConfig, int16_t minTemp,
                         int16_t maxTemp, uint16_t table[]);

/******************************************************************************
* Global Functions
******************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{
    ntc_config_t ntcConfig;
    long double voltRef = 5.0;
    long double res;
    int16_t minTemp = -40;
    int16_t maxTemp;
    uint16_t *table;
    int tableSize = 0;

    printf("This program will generate the NTC table based on various inputs.\n\n");
    // Beta
    printf("Beta: ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.beta);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.beta);

    // Pull up resistance
    printf("Pull-up Resistance: ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.rntc);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.rntc);

    // Reference temp
    printf("Reference Temperature (Degrees C): ");
    scanf("%hhu", &ntcConfig.refTemp);
    printf("%hhu\n", ntcConfig.refTemp);

    // Reference resistance
    printf("Reference Resistance (Ohms): ");
    scanf("%d", &ntcConfig.refRes);
    printf("%d\n", ntcConfig.refRes);

    // ADC voltage reference
    printf("ADC Reference Voltage: ");
    scanf("%Lf", &voltRef);
    printf("%Lf\n", voltRef);

    // ADC resolutions (in bits)
    printf("ADC Resolution (in bits): ");
    scanf("%Lf", &res);
    printf("%Lf\n", res);

    // NTC Register Resolution
    NtcRegisterRes = (long double)voltRef / pow(2, res);
    printf("%Le\n", NtcRegisterRes);

    // Min Temp for Table
    printf("Min Temp: ");
    scanf("%" SCNd16, &minTemp);
    printf("min temp: %d\n", minTemp);

    // Max Temp for Table
    printf("Max Temp: ");
    scanf("%" SCNd16, &maxTemp);
    printf("max temp: %d\n", maxTemp);    

    tableSize = (maxTemp + abs(minTemp)) + 1;
    printf("table size: %d\n", tableSize);
    table = (uint16_t *)malloc(tableSize * sizeof(uint16_t));
    FillNtcTable(&ntcConfig, minTemp, maxTemp, table);
    
    // Print table
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        printf("Temp:\t%d\tADC:\t%d\n", (minTemp+i), table[i]);
    }

    // Free the memory
    free(table);

    return(0);
}

/******************************************************************************
* Local Functions
******************************************************************************/
/*!
 * @brief This function fills the NTC look up table.
 *
 * NTC look up table is intended for resistance to temperature conversion.
 * An array item contains raw value from a register. Index of the item is
 * temperature value.
 *
 * ArrayItem = (Vcom * Rntc) / (0.00015258789 * (NTC + Rntc))
 * Where:
 *  - ArrayItem is an item value of the table,
 *  - Vcom is maximal voltage (5V),
 *  - NTC is the resistance of NTC thermistor (Ohm),
 *  - 0.00015258789 is resolution of measured voltage in Volts
 *    (V = 152.58789 uV * Register_value),
 *  - Rntc is value of a resistor connected to Vcom (see MC3377x datasheet,
 *    section MC3377x PCB components).
 *
 * Beta formula used to calculate temperature based on NTC resistance:
 *   1 / T = 1 / T0 + (1 / Beta) * ln(Rt / R0)
 * Where:
 *  - R0 is the resistance (Ohm) at temperature T0 (Kelvin),
 *  - Beta is material constant (Kelvin),
 *  - T is temperature corresponding to resistance of the NTC thermistor.
 *
 * Equation for NTC value is given from the Beta formula:
 *   NTC = R0 * exp(Beta * (1/T - 1/T0))
 *
 * @param ntcConfig Pointer to NTC components configuration.
 */
static void FillNtcTable(const ntc_config_t* const ntcConfig, int16_t minTemp,
                         int16_t maxTemp, uint16_t table[])
{
    double ntcVal;
    double expArg;
    uint16_t i = 0;
    int32_t temp;

    for (temp = minTemp; temp <= maxTemp; temp++)
    {
        expArg = ntcConfig->beta * ((1.0 / (NTC_DEGC_0 + temp)) - (1.0 / (NTC_DEGC_0 + ntcConfig->refTemp)));
        ntcVal = exp(expArg) * ntcConfig->refRes;
        table[i] = (uint16_t)round(((NTC_VCOM * ntcVal) / (ntcVal + (double)ntcConfig->rntc)) / NtcRegisterRes);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I used the compiler in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler so let me know if this solution works on yours. Else, I will remove this solution.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford you were right. If I change minTemp and maxTemp to int's, it works. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I'll try that out also.

Comment: "to use the library inttypes.h" this is not really correct. `inttypes.h` is not a library. It is only a header of C standard library. The standard library is already included as `scanf` is also part of it. Being precise is important as especially beginners might mix up headers with libraries which will cause confusion lateron.

Comment: @Gerhardh you are right. I shouldn't do generalization.

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int*` but you are passing a pointer to a narrower type `int16_t`.  So you write 32-bits where only 16 are available, overwriting whatever happens to be adjacent.

You should either:

```
int input = 0 ;
scanf("%d", &input) ;
minTemp = (int16_t)input ;
```

or

```
scanf("%" SCNd16, &minTemp ) ;
```

and similarly for `maxTemp` of course.

Or more simply reconsider the data type you are using.  Do they need to be `int16_t`? Is there good reason for that?  The data type choices all round seem rather arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you @Clifford you were right. If I change minTemp and maxTemp to int's, it works. I appreciate the help!